# save product details in custom table & display below My account

Tags: magento-1.9, database, customer-account

Once Registered customers click on "**Create Product**" button present in product view page, we are creating new product in database. now we need to

**1)Save those newly created product details in custom Table : my_designs**

we are successfuly doing with help of this code :

```
$data = array('title'=>fav1_id,'product_id'=>$product->getId(),'customer_id'=>
 Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getId());
$model = Mage::getModel('example/mydesign')->setData($data);
```

[image]

**2)display those products in My Designs** section in Customer's **My Account** by fetching values from `my_designs` table.

I am using module & I am trying below code to display those products under **My Designs** section.

**Issue** : in **customer 1's Dashboard** only **Products created by customer 1** should display, but now its displaying all customer's Products.

```
<?php $collections = $this->getCollection(); ?>
<?php foreach ($collections as $key => $product) {
    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getProductId());        
    echo $product->getId().'<br />';
    echo $_product->getName().'<br />';

}
?>
```

full module : http://www.filedropper.com/amasty-module1

Comment: i will give 100 bounty points if it worked for me.....

Comment: Did you save product in my_design table once click Create Product. I mean it saved Database

Comment: You want to create new product or in view page that paroduct to save my_design table

Comment: @Kothari I am creating new product once click on button & now i need to save that product to `my_design` table, so that i can display under `My designs` under `My account`

Comment: Do you pragmatically save the products as simple products or its totally different product?

Comment: @Mujahidh yes, i programtically create new product once customer click on `button` which is present in product view page.....

Comment: Murtuza Zabuawala given you the best sollution. You can work  according to his answer.

Comment: @BabyinMagento check updated answer

Comment: @Mujahidh i need solution to save product informations in custom table....

Comment: can you provide detail code because this link wont work for me .

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala please join http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55266/assign

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below code will get you products for a customer.

Update your file **app\code\local\Amasty\Example\Block\List.php::__construct()**

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $idc = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getId();
    $customerSavedProductArray = array();
    $customerSavedProductArray = Mage::getModel('example/mydesign')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',$idc)->getColumnValues("product_id");
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array("in"=>$customerSavedProductArray));
    $collection->load();
    $this->setCollection($collection);
}
```

Now update file **app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\example\example.phtml**

```
<?php $collections = $this->getCollection(); ?>
<?php foreach ($collections as $key => $product) {
    //$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getProductId());    
    //echo $product->getProductUrl().'<br />';
    echo $product->getId().'<br />';
    echo $product->getName().'<br />';
    //echo $_product->getImage().'<br />';
    //echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')->getMediaUrl( $product->getImage() ).'<br />'; 
    //echo $_product->getFinalPrice();'<br />';
}
?>
<!--
<img id="product-collection-image-<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>"
                                     src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image'); ?>"
                                     alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>"/>

-->
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable time......  it worked fine.....

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use different attribute set for that kind of product ,

and one of that attribute contains the `customer_id` and filter product collection using that `customer_id` attribute basis

and show them in  users dashboard.

For filtering product you can use below code

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('customer_id',array('eq'=>$customer_id));
foreach($collection as $product){
   echo $product->getId();
}
```

Comment: yes i created different attribute set as `custom_Design` & created new attribue `customer_id`  for that attribute set, please help me for `filter product collection using that customer_id attribute basis`

Comment: @BabyinMagento provide me the link

Comment: please check [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/custom-apple-iphone-4.html) , you can see `create` button next to `add tocart` and `save design`

Comment: Provide me question link

Comment: I mentioned in this question only that i need to display products under `My Designs` section.... i need to save in DB, than only i can display in `My Designs` , please help me to save in Db

Comment: please check updated question once.....